# Laravel - Class 'Database\Factories\Core\User\Domain\Entities\UserFactory' not found

Tags: laravel, testing, factory

I'm using ADR architecture with Laravel in my new project.
I've created ADR for the User which contains the Actions, Domain, Responder folder. I've defined User Model In `Core\User\Domain\Entities` which has code like below:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
use HasFactory, Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];
}
```

Now I have UserFactory that extends `Core\User\Domain\Entities\User`. but when I want to use UserFactory with this code `$user = User::factory()->create()` I get this error:

```
Error: Class 'Database\Factories\Core\User\Domain\Entities\UserFactory' not found
```

How can I solve this Error? Do I have to move my Model to the previous location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by adding this code to the AppServiceProvider:

```
public function register()
{
    Factory::guessFactoryNamesUsing(function ($class) {
        return 'Database\\Factories\\' . class_basename($class) . 'Factory';
    });
}
```